# Slug size too large

Tags: django, heroku, pytorch, slug

I tried to deploy my app on heroku, but have following error.
Compiled slug size: 869M is too large (max is 500M).

I am wondering if i can increase the slug size by chancing Dyno types (ex. change free to standard)?

Comment: Why is your slug so big? You've only tagged [tag:heroku] and [tag:django]. Are you doing machine learning or something?

Comment: Yes, I'm using torch (cpu only) for machine learning, but still over 500mb